# (Three.JS) Transform controls for translation (Size Issue)

Tags: javascript, three.js, transform

I am working on customizing the transform controls available in three.js for my project.
I have already changed the rotation part and now working on translation part.
if you notice in translation Gizmo, there is a XYZ octahedron in the center. I have removed all other planes and arrows and wrote all functionality only on that center mesh, which is working fine.
Now I am only stuck at one small problem, that is the size and position of that controller. I changed that Octahedron to boxGeometry and writing the code to make the size of that controller to be exact size of the selected object. for that I get the idea to make the size of the controller, same as the boxHelper size, which act as outline of object.
when I tried this logic in sample code, where I created a box, and getting the size of box helper and creating another box of same size, it was working fine. but when I am writing same code in threejs transform controls, result is not the same.

below is the geometry code init

```
 XYZ: [[ new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ), pickerMaterial )]],
```

then I am getting the size of box3 when attaching to any object

```
  this.addBoxHelper = function () {
        this.removeBoxHelper();

        if(this.object.box3) {
            **this.object.box3.getSize(selectionBoxSize);**
            console.log(selectionBoxSize)

            this.objectBoxHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(this.object.box3, 0xffff00);
            this.objectBoxHelper.canSelect = function () {
                return false;
            }
            this.object.add(this.objectBoxHelper);
        }
    }
```

then below is my update function of transform controls

```
    this.update = function () {

        if ( scope.object === undefined ) return;

        scope.object.updateMatrixWorld();
        worldPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( scope.object.matrixWorld );
        worldRotation.setFromRotationMatrix( tempMatrix.extractRotation( scope.object.matrixWorld ) );
        scope.object.box3.getSize(selectionBoxSize);
        scope.object.getWorldPosition(selectionBoxPos);

        camera.updateMatrixWorld();
        camPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( camera.matrixWorld );
        camRotation.setFromRotationMatrix( tempMatrix.extractRotation( camera.matrixWorld ) );

        **scaleT = selectionBoxSize;** 

//below three lines are for dynamic size change based on camera position..for 
//next level functionality

         //scaleT.x = worldPosition.distanceTo( camPosition ) / 6 * selectionBoxSize.x;
         //scaleT.y = worldPosition.distanceTo( camPosition ) / 6 * selectionBoxSize.y;
         //scaleT.z = worldPosition.distanceTo( camPosition ) / 6    * selectionBoxSize.z;


        this.position.copy( selectionBoxPos );


        this.scale.set( scaleT.x, scaleT.y, scaleT.z);
        this.updateMatrixWorld();
```

below is the output of console log

> TransformControls.js:526 Vector3 {x: 10.020332336425781, y: 2.621583938598633, z: 3.503500819206238}
>
> TransformControls.js:601 Vector3 {x: 10.020332336425781, y: 2.621583938598633, z: 3.503500819206238}

as you can see, the scale is the same, but the result is different. see the result in below images.

[image: result_1]
[image: result_2]

as you see in images, that red color box at bottom is translation controller but smaller than selection box.
another issue is that pivot of my objects are at bottom, and I want this controller to come at the center of the selection box, that is also not happening with getCenter method of box3.

Please help!! let me know if I am unclear in explaining the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the bounding box of the object from its geometry, that will be wrong because it doesn't take the objects transform into account. You have to use box3.setFromObject (yourObject) instead. does that help?

Comment: I tried with all possible ways to bring it to same size. still it is not working.below is the code...
 `if(!this.box3) { 
this.box3 = new THREE.Box3().setFromCustomObjects(this);
            //this.box3 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this);
        }'

Comment: What is "setFromCustomObjects" ? I don't see it in the docs. You should probably post some kind of minimal example that shows your problem. What version of THREE are you running?

Comment: setfromcustomobjects is my project function. My silly mistake is i uncomment it before posting here..what I want to tell you is that I tried with setFromObjects also but it was not working. You can see it, I just commented before posting.. Regarding the minimal viable example, this is huge project. I will try to get the control file out and post an example in some time.